# Manually building a deep copy of a ConfigParser in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, deep-copy, configparser

Just starting in on my Python learning curve, and hitting a snag in porting some code up to Python 2.7.  It appears that in Python 2.7 it is no longer possible to perform a deepcopy() on instances of ConfigParser.  It also appears that the Python team isn't terribly interested in restoring such a capability:

http://bugs.python.org/issue16058

Can someone propose an elegant solution for manually constructing a deepcopy/duplicate of an instance of ConfigParser?

Many thanks, -Pete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on @Toenex answer, modified for Python 2.7:

```
import StringIO
import ConfigParser

# Create a deep copy of the configuration object
config_string = StringIO.StringIO()
base_config.write(config_string)

# We must reset the buffer to make it ready for reading.        
config_string.seek(0)        
new_config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
new_config.readfp(config_string)
```

Answer (score 7):

This is just an example implementation of Jan Vlcinsky answer written in Python 3 (I don't have enough reputation to post this as a comment to Jans answer).  Many thanks to Jan for the push in the right direction.

To make a full (deep) copy of `base_config` into `new_config` just do the following;

```
import io
import configparser

config_string = io.StringIO()
base_config.write(config_string)
# We must reset the buffer ready for reading.
config_string.seek(0) 
new_config = configparser.ConfigParser()
new_config.read_file(config_string)
```

Comment: Doesn't work with ExtendedInterpolation. See alternate solution.

Answer (score 3):

The previous solution doesn't work in all *python3* use cases. Specifically if the original parser is using [Extended Interpolation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/configparser.html#interpolation-of-values) the copy may fail to work correctly. Fortunately, the easy solution is to use the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) module:

```
def deep_copy(config:configparser.ConfigParser)->configparser.ConfigParser:
    """deep copy config"""
    rep = pickle.dumps(config)
    new_config = pickle.loads(rep)
    return new_config
```

Comment: ... and it works with "almost" all kinds of objects. Great trick!

Answer (score 1):

If you need new independent copy of ConfigParser, then one option is:

- have original version of ConfigParser
- serialize the config file into temporary file or StringIO buffer
- use that tmpfile or StringIO buffer to create new ConfigParser.

And you have it done.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 3 (3.2+) you can use the [Mapping Protocol Access](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#mapping-protocol-access) to copy (actually deep copy) the sections and options of a source configuration to another [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser) object.

You can use [`read_dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read_dict) to copy the state of a configuration parser.

Here is a demo:

```py
import configparser

# the configuration to deep copy:
src_cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
src_cfg.add_section("Section A")
src_cfg["Section A"]["key1"] = "value1"
src_cfg["Section A"]["key2"] = "value2"

# the destination configuration
dst_cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
dst_cfg.read_dict(src_cfg)
dst_cfg.add_section("Section B")
dst_cfg["Section B"]["key3"] = "value3"
```

To display the resulting configuration, you can try:

```py
import io

output = io.StringIO()
dst_cfg.write(output)
print(output.getvalue())
```

You get:

```
[Section A]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2

[Section B]
key3 = value3
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading this article, I am more familiar with config.ini.

Record as follows:

```
import io
import configparser


def copy_config_demo():
    with io.StringIO() as memory_file:
        memory_file.write(str(test_config_data.__doc__))  # original_config.write(memory_file)
        memory_file.seek(0)
        new_config = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=configparser.ExtendedInterpolation())
        new_config.read_file(memory_file)

    # below is just for test
    for section_name, list_item in [(section_name, new_config.items(section_name)) for section_name in new_config.sections()]:
        print('\n[' + section_name + ']')
        for key, value in list_item:
            print(f'{key}: {value}')


def test_config_data():
    """
    [Common]
    home_dir: /Users
    library_dir: /Library
    system_dir: /System
    macports_dir: /opt/local

    [Frameworks]
    Python: >=3.2
    path: ${Common:system_dir}/Library/Frameworks/

    [Arthur]
    name: Carson
    my_dir: ${Common:home_dir}/twosheds
    my_pictures: ${my_dir}/Pictures
    python_dir: ${Frameworks:path}/Python/Versions/${Frameworks:Python}
    """
```

**output:**

```
[Common]
home_dir: /Users
library_dir: /Library
system_dir: /System
macports_dir: /opt/local

[Frameworks]
python: >=3.2
path: /System/Library/Frameworks/

[Arthur]
name: Carson
my_dir: /Users/twosheds
my_pictures: /Users/twosheds/Pictures
python_dir: /System/Library/Frameworks//Python/Versions/>=3.2
```

hoping it is helpful to you.